# Opamp output is not stable

Tags: operational-amplifier

In my circuit I am using lm324 opamp.

Input is connected to the inverting pin using 10k resistor.
Non inverting pin is connected to GND using 10k resistor.
Feedback resistor is 10k. In this configuration output is not stable for stable input signal.
[image]

Comment: did you check your lm328? because if you bought this one from eBay or aliexpress it could be a bad chip.

Comment: what are you applying on its power supply inputs? what is the amplitude and waveform of the signal?

Comment: I am applying  output of previous stage obtain from sensor output which is 400mv approximately

Comment: Just to verify my assumptions, the feedback resistor is connected to the inverting input, correct?

Comment: Absolutely and one more thing the same inverting pin is connected to the one POT wiper pin using 10K resistor. And POT is connected between GND and +5V supply.POT is 2K value.

Comment: Are you sure it is LM328? That seems to be a DC-DC converter, not an op amp.

Comment: Sorry it's my bad. It is lm324 .

Comment: No problem. What is the voltage at your non-inverting input? Do you just have the one resistor pulling it toward ground? You are probably saturating your op amp unless you have a +5V/-5V/Gnd supply.

Comment: Is there any problem GND with resistor of 10 k??? I am not knowing this thing

Comment: On inverting input i am feeding 400mv. On non inverting pin 10k connected to the GND.

Comment: Insert your circuit for clear discussions.

Comment: Please provide a circuit diagram, people will be more inclined to help you if you make the effort to qualify your question properly. At least half of the comments here are folks trying to work out what you've actually built without sufficient detail provided.

Comment: Ok sir i will provide ckt

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your circuit looks something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZAtq4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem is that the non-inverting input to the op-amp needs to be held at some reference point other than the negative supply rail (in this case ground) for the op-amp to work, unless your input is always negative.

Here's why.

An op amp is designed so that *if it can*, it will create an output signal which is, to a first approximation, an amplified copy of the difference in voltages between the input pins. Considered by itself, an op amp has a very large voltage gain--often in the range of 100,000 to 1,000,000. So, a very slight difference in the voltages on the input pins can result in a very large voltage at the output. However, that's what it does *if it can*. But an op amp's ability to output any particular voltage is limited by the voltages available to it, and its internal circuitry. An op amp cannot output a voltage greater than its positive supply voltage, nor less than its negative supply voltage. Many op amps, because of their internal circuitry, cannot even output that large a range. Their maximum range might be limited to the positive supply voltage -2V, down to their negative supply voltage +2 volts. Whatever their range is, whether it be "rail to rail", or less than that, the op amp cannot output beyond that range no matter what the voltages are on the input pins. When the output has reached the end of its range, either high or low, the op amp is said to be saturated.

Now, consider an op amp whose non-inverting input is at the same voltage as its negative supply rail. If the inverting input pin is slightly more positive than the non-inverting input pin, then the op amp will want to output a "negative" signal, one below the voltage of the non-inverting input pin. But, it can't do that, because the non-inverting input pin is already at the lowest voltage available to the op amp. So the op amp will saturate, and give an output at its low limit.

On the other hand, if the non-inverting input is at the same voltage as the negative supply rail, and the inverting input pin is slightly more negative than the non-inverting input pin, that means that the inverting input pin is *below* the negative supply rail. Although this might work in some cases for some op amps, such an input is generally outside of the recommended operating conditions.

So, in either case, if the non-inverting input pin is at the same voltage as the negative supply rail, the op amp will not do it's job properly. The same reasoning applies if the non-inverting input pin is at the same voltage as its positive supply rail. The non-inverting input pin needs to be somewhere in between, and generally not just in between the positive and negative supply rails, but in between the positive and negative limits of its output range.

You were wise to not leave the non-inverting input pin floating. That would not work. But in tying the non-inverting input to ground through a resistor, you did not set its voltage at an appropriate value.

Tying the non-inverting pin to ground would work *if* you had a bipolar supply. For example, if you had the positive supply pin at +5V, the negative supply pin at -5V, and a GND in between.

Often it is simultaneously *inconvenient* to have a bipolar supply and also unnecessary. It can be unnecessary, because there is a work around for operating op amps with a single supply voltage and a ground. One can set the non-inverting input pin to a value between the rails using a voltage divider.

An example of how one might go about doing this is to add a second 10K resistor from the non-inverting input to \$V_{cc}\$. That will make your reference voltage 2.5V. The output will then swing around that 2.5V reference.

Your circuit will then look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsPkTh.png)</sup>

Comment: Absolutely sir but inveting pin is also connected to one 10k resistor to the POT wiper pin and pot is connected in between +5v and gnd

Comment: Does it look right now?

Comment: you should refer to the allowed common input range.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Thank you for the suggestion. I added an explanation.

Comment: Hello sir i have attcahed circuit for opamp configuration.

Comment: Thank you. Your sketch does not show power supply connections to your op amp. Does my "answer" answer your question?

Comment: Sir there is +5v and GND is connected to the supply pins. I am getting output but that output is not stable.

Comment: I was just mentioning that they are not on your sketch. Others may want to know. I understand that you are not getting a stable output. What is your opinion of my answer? Does it make sense to you? Am I missing something?